# Applied SP2013 November CU and 2010 workflow still do not work

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, cumulative-update

I'm curious if anyone has had the issue described here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/09/11/net-framework-september-2018-security-and-quality-rollup/

> After any of the September 2018 .NET Framework security updates to resolve CVE-2018-8421 (.NET Framework Remote Code Execution Vulnerability) are applied, SharePoint out-of-the-box workflows stop working.

The November CU lists that it resolves this issue, but when I applied the update I was still unable to use an out of the box 2010 workflow. I can see in central admin that the update has been installed successfully.

Here's the article for resolving the issue:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4465015/sharepoint-workflows-stop-after-cve-2018-8421-security-update

> The solution is to explicitly add the necessary types to all web applications' web.config files.

I checked the web.config file and the additional settings outlined in the article were not present. I'm wondering if I still need to make these changes to the web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can check the detailed information in the blog below:

[After installing .NET security patches to address CVE-2018-8421, SharePoint workflows stop working (KB 4457916/4457035 and others)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rodneyviana/2018/09/13/after-installing-net-security-patches-to-address-cve-2018-8421-sharepoint-workflows-stop-working/)

If the issue exists, try to clear the SharePoint Configuration cache, restart your server and run IISRESET.

[Clear SharePoint configuration cache](https://www.zubairalexander.com/blog/clearing-the-sharepoint-configuration-cache/)